# (Fast) searching in spite of row inheritance

Tags: mysql, search

I currently have a table which has these columns:

```
id (INT)
parent_id (INT)
col0
col1
col2
```

As an example there are the following entries saved in this table:

```
1     NULL   abc     def     NULL
2     1      test    NULL    NULL
3     1      NULL    NULL    xyz
```

Now I'd like to search in all rows A which haven't got any rows B which are pointing to them (B.parent_id = A.id). In addition the row values should be either the ones that are present in the current row or if there is a NULL, the values of the parent should be considered.

To illustrate my requirements I'd like to show some examples:

```
SEARCH(col0=test) => #2 (#1 has some children, #3.col0 = abc (inherited from #1))
SEARCH(col1=def) => #2, #3 (#1 has some children)
SEARCH(col2=xyz) => #3 (#1 has some children, #2.col2 = NULL (inherited from #1))
```

Does anyone know how to implement such a search in MySQL?

Comment: Give some example rows and the desired result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
# if first table has no value, use parent table
IF(t1.col0, t1.col0, t2.col0) as virtcol0,
IF(t1.col1, t1.col1, t2.col1) as virtcol1,
IF(t1.col2, t1.col2, t2.col2) as virtcol2
FROM table as t1
LEFT JOIN table as t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table as t3 ON t1.id = t3.parent_id
# t3 would be children of t1. We don't want t1 to procreate. :)
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
# Your actual search goes here:
AND virtcol0/1/2 = whatever
```

Fast? No. Best index use you can get out of this are the joins on id/parent_id.

If you have a lot of data and small result sets, you can query the columns directly on an index and then run checks for parents and children in separate queries. That'd be a lot faster than running the above query on a huge table.

Comment: If your result can contain numeric zero or empty strings, you may want to adjust the IFs to IS NOT NULL.

Comment: ...or even [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

Comment: Never heard of that one before. Quite useful! :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this works until there is a depth bigger than 3? Is there any possibility to support unlimited depth?

Comment: Should be possible using a loop: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while-statement.html. But this is really outside the scope of what I'd do in an SQL query. :)

Comment: Alright, thank you! I will implement the tree in an other table and each time an update occurs, I will update all rows individually. As there are not much updates but lots of SELECTs, this is AFAIK the most efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution would probably be to create a view with the parent and child columns merged:

```
CREATE VIEW foo
AS SELECT
  c.id AS id,
  COALESCE(c.col0, p.col0) AS col0,
  COALESCE(c.col1, p.col1) AS col1,
  COALESCE(c.col2, p.col2) AS col2
FROM table AS c
  LEFT JOIN table AS p ON p.id = c.parent_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM table AS x WHERE c.id = x.parent_id)
```

Then you can write queries against this view as if it were a normal table.

However, as Mantriur notes, this will *not* be very efficient.  If the table doesn't change very often, you could use [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) instead of `CREATE VIEW` to create an actual table containing the merged data and create some indexes on it so that it can be efficiently queried.  However, such a table won't track changes to the original table the way a view does.

In principle, you could use triggers (or application logic) to update the merged table in real time as the underlying table changes, but this can easily get complicated and prone to errors.  Unfortunately, while some other RDBMSes do support [materialized views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view), which are essentially a way to do this automatically, MySQL currently does not.

(Well, not natively, anyway.  There *is* [Flexviews](http://code.google.com/p/flexviews/), although I haven't tried it myself.)